# How to use MAX() for multiple dates in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, max, date-arithmetic

My goal is to choose the PTID with the most recent date with its recent time. I was trying to use the MAX() function to choose the most recent date with its recent time but received an error syntax (see the double asterisk on Line 9 in my code). Is there a statement to do that or would it be easier to do it in Python? I appreciate all the help!

Table 1

| PTID | RESULT_DATE1 | RESULT_TIME | DIAGNOSIS_CD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 54 | 2020-01-06 | 10:03:02 | W34 |
| 54 | 2020-01-01 | 09:18:05 | S38 |
| 54 | 2020-01-01 | 03:08:45 | V98 |
| 54 | 2020-04-04 | 02:09:08 | V98 |
| 54 | 2020-04-04 | 12:12:34 | V89 |

My Goal:

| PTID | RESULT_DATE1 | RESULT_TIME | DIAGNOSIS_CD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 54 | 2020-04-04 | 12:12:34 | V98 |
| 54 | 2020-01-06 | 10:03:02 | W34 |
| 54 | 2020-01-01 | 09:18:05 | S38 |

My Code:

```
CREATE TABLE covid AS
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM lab9 t1 JOIN diagnosis9 t2 ON t2.PTID = t1.PTID 
AND t1.RESULT_DATE1 || ' ' || t1.RESULT_TIME
BETWEEN 
date(t2.diagdate1, '-7 day') || ' ' || t2.DIAG_TIME
AND 
t2.diagdate1 || ' ' || t2.DIAG_TIME
**WHERE RESULT_DATE1 = MAX(RESULT_DATE1)** 
GROUP BY t1.PTID || DIAGNOSIS_CD 
ORDER BY t1.PTID;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should not group by the concatenation of 2 columns because this may lead to unexpected results.
You should group by the 2 columns.

Also, you can't use an aggregate function like `MAX()` in the `WHERE` clause of a query.

What you need is the max value of the expression `t1.RESULT_DATE1 || ' ' || t1.RESULT_TIME` which you can finally split to date and time with the functions `date()` and `time()`:

```
CREATE TABLE covid AS
SELECT t1.PTID, 
       date(MAX(t1.RESULT_DATE1 || ' ' || t1.RESULT_TIME)) RESULT_DATE1,
       time(MAX(t1.RESULT_DATE1 || ' ' || t1.RESULT_TIME)) RESULT_TIME,
       t2.*
FROM lab9 t1 JOIN diagnosis9 t2 
ON t2.PTID = t1.PTID 
AND t1.RESULT_DATE1 || ' ' || t1.RESULT_TIME
    BETWEEN 
    date(t2.diagdate1, '-7 day') || ' ' || t2.DIAG_TIME AND t2.diagdate1 || ' ' || t2.DIAG_TIME
GROUP BY t1.PTID, t2.DIAGNOSIS_CD 
ORDER BY t1.PTID;
```

The above query will return the rows with the max datetime for each combination of `PTID` and `DIAGNOSIS_CD` with the use if SQLite's feature of [bare columns](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#bare_columns_in_an_aggregate_query).

Comment: This worked! Thank you for the explanation as well as I am adjusting to SQLite.